# I've created a voting calculator, but one line of code seems to mess up another section. Is it my variables?

Tags: python, calculator

I have a fairly complex (to me, but probably simple for python experts) code from my python class that analyzes a local election: it tallies votes and then prints the results (candidates+votes, counties+votes, election winner). The results I come up with are spot on...except for one piece, which I've commented in the code with "# !Something in this line is causing the Winner/Winning Vote Count and Winning Percentage to get thrown out!" With that preceding line of code in there the election winner results below it don't print (the section does, but the winner's name and vote totals don't). If I remove that piece of code, the wrong county is identified as the "county with the most votes" (largest_county; Arapahoe instead of Denver, where Denver is the correct county with the most votes), but then the winner of the election is printed correctly.

The two sections of code that print these pieces of information -- county with the most votes and winner of the election -- are virtually the same code, just with different variables. I'm wondering if some variable I declared in there is maybe doubling up or being incremented twice, but I can't figure out what it might be. Maybe the "votes" variable? Any help would be appreciated.

```
# snip some code

# Candidate Options list and candidate votes dictionary.
candidate_options = []
candidate_votes = {}

# 1: Create a county list and county votes dictionary.
counties = []
county_votes = {}

# Track the winning candidate, vote count and percentage
winning_candidate = ""
winning_count = 0
winning_percentage = 0

# 2: Track the largest county and county voter turnout.
largest_county = ""
largest_count = 0
largest_percentage = 0

# snip some code

        if candidate_name not in candidate_options:

            # Add the candidate name to the candidate list.
            candidate_options.append(candidate_name)

            # And begin tracking that candidate's voter count.
            candidate_votes[candidate_name] = 0

        # Add a vote to that candidate's count
        candidate_votes[candidate_name] += 1

        # 4a: Write a decision statement that checks that the county does not match any existing county in the county list.
        if county_name not in counties:

            # 4b: Add the existing county to the list of counties.
            counties.append(county_name)

            # 4c: Begin tracking the county's vote count.
            county_votes[county_name] = 0

        # 5: Add a vote to that county's vote count.
        county_votes[county_name] += 1

# snip some code

            winning_count = votes
            largest_county = county_name
            largest_percentage = vote_percentage
    
    # 7: Print the county with the largest turnout to the terminal.
    largest_county_summary = (
        f"-------------------------\n"
        f"County with largest turnout: {largest_county}\n"
        f"-------------------------\n")
    print(largest_county_summary)
    
# snip some code

        # Determine winning vote count, winning percentage, and candidate.
        if (votes > winning_count) and (vote_percentage > winning_percentage):
            winning_count = votes
            winning_candidate = candidate_name
            winning_percentage = vote_percentage

# snip some code
```

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask; tldr; if you make your question crisp, and to the point, you'll have a better chance of attracting quality answers too.

Comment: wdym by 'Winning Vote Count and Winning Percentage to get thrown out'?

Comment: Have you considered a possibility where two candidates can have same name across two counties. How are you handling it? Shouldn't the votes be tallied by county by candidate? Ex: {county1:{candidate1:n, candidate2:m},county2:{candidate3:p, candidate4:q}}  in this case if candidate1 and candidate4 are same, it won't mess up the votes. Also are you going to determine the total votes in the state vs each county? The total votes should be by county. The % votes by county and candidate has to match as well.  If this is for general election, then my comment may need tweaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error is here:

```
if (votes > largest_count) and (vote_percentage > largest_percentage):
    winning_count = votes
    largest_county = county_name
    largest_percentage = vote_percentage
```

Instead of `winning_count = votes`, you should assign `largest_count = votes`

Comment: Wow, that's so painfully obvious that it makes sense why I didn't see it now ;-P Thank you so much.

Comment: Since this question has been answered, you should acknowledge the answer and close this out.